# What can I have as a Maven artifact and how can I use it?

Tags: java, maven, build

I know that it seems like a question that is already asked, but I have not found an answer that helps me a lot.

I read a lot of times that it is preferable to generate an artifact per project. But my question is : what can I have as a Maven artifact?

For example : I have a custom packaging "MyPack" with a custom lifecycle, can I have whole a directory "Mydirectory" as an artefact?

Let's say that the structure of the directory is like this:

MyDirectory

-----|--jars

-----|-----|--- client.jar

-----|-----|--- server.jar

-----|--jsps

-----|-----|--- page1.jsp

-----|-----|--- page2.jsp

-----|--imgs

-----|-----|--- img1.png

-----|-----|--- img2.png

Then, I want to create a new project that has the packaging "MyPack" and a dependency with the type "MyPack". In this project, my Java classes need client.jar and server.jar which are in the Maven repository to compile and I want to copy all jsps and imgs from the repository in my new project.

can I do all that with a custom Maven plugin?

Answer (score 0):

You can have as maven artifact whatever you choose to have as an artifact. 
Use the [maven assembly plugin](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-assembly-plugin/) to generate the artifact:

```
    <build>
       <plugins>
          <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.4</version>
            <configuration>
                <descriptors>
                    <descriptor>${basedir}/src/main/assembly/shared.xml</descriptor>
                </descriptors>
            </configuration>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <phase>package</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>single</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
     ....
      </plugins> 
     ....
  </build>
```

In the shared.xml file you specify the format and files to be included in the artifact:

```
<assembly xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-assembly-plugin/assembly/1.1.2"
      xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
      xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-assembly-plugin/assembly/1.1.2 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/assembly-1.1.2.xsd">
<id>shared</id>
<formats>
    <format>jar</format>
</formats>
<includeBaseDirectory>false</includeBaseDirectory>
<fileSets>
    <fileSet>
        <outputDirectory>/</outputDirectory>                            
        <directory>${basedir}/.....</directory>
        <includes>
            <include> ... </include>
        </includes>
        <fileMode>0644</fileMode>
        <filtered>false</filtered>
        <lineEnding>unix</lineEnding>
    </fileSet>
  </fileSets>
</assembly>
```

When you do "maven deploy", the "shared" artifact will be packaged and deployed together with the project's main artifact. 
In order to use the artifact in another project, use the [maven-dependency-plugin](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-dependency-plugin/) with the goal "unpack-dependencies".

Comment: Thank you for your answer @esalagea.
After using the "unpack-dependencies" goal, should I use a dependency with "System" scope to add jars client.jar and server.jar to the classpath of my new project or is there an other solution?